# haxe/nme loading screen

Tags: haxe, nme

How can I specify what should be displayed while my app loads? I was expecting something similar to Flex, where you can set a custom sprite with the preloader property of the Application class. Then this sprite is displayed while preloading, an that sprite is loaded before everything else. I was expecting some tag for this in the nmml file, but looking here:

http://www.haxenme.org/developers/documentation/nmml-project-files/

I can't find anything...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes that seems to be it! I saw that link in a google search result before but didn't click it because it had "iOS and Android" in the title. But I see that it is generic once I actually read the page.. :) Ok will give it a test and see how it goes..

Comment: Ok worked like a charm! Peace and love to Haxe and the community!

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide an answer in case someone has the same question. It is done in the nmml file in the app tag, like so:

```
<app ... preloader="com.myapp.MyPreloader" />
```

Then the preloader class should extend `NMEPreloader` which has a number of functions you can override, most noticeably an `onUpdate` method.